# RuntimeError: Model class project6.models.Emp doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

I declared models.py in project directory. Don't have any apps. If we make the form at project level then its run but when we add that form with database through models then occurs the 'run time error'.
"RuntimeError: Model class project6.models.Emp doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS."

I have tried many times to resolve but not successed. Please resolve this problem

**All are in projects directory**

This is my views

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
# from .forms import InputForm
from .models import Emp, Man

from .forms import ContactForm


# Views
@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, "registration/success.html", {})


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})

def maker(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            emp = form.cleaned_data['emp']
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            man = form.cleaned_data['man']
            p = Emp.objects.create(emp=emp, name=name, email=email)
            q = Man.objects.create(man=man)
            # messages.success(request, 'Form submission successful')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
    return render(request, 'success.html', {'form': form})
```

THis is my models

```
from django.db import models


class Emp(models.Model):
  emp = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  mail = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
  objects: models.Manager()

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name


class Man(models.Model):
  man = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  emp = models.ForeignKey(Emp, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  objects: models.Manager()

  def __str__(self):
      return self.man
```

This is my urls

````
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('form/', views.maker, name='form'),

]```
````

Comment: add your app_name to INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py

Comment: don't have any apps

Comment: you can't create your models.py in your main project dir you have to create a app for that because django doesn't allow to create models in you project dir first create then it that create you models because i also tried the same thing while learning django

Comment: @shreyashmishra thanks for your response. Can you please tell me how to add models of app directly with views of project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to create an application in Django with the command `python manage.py startapp your_app_name`, this makes your setup simple and manageable if you don't want to make an app, then you have to configure a lot of [stuff](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/07/a-minimal-django-application.html) by yourself(which is not recommended unless you know what you do)

After making the app you have to register your app in settings.py by adding the newly created app name to `INSTALLED_APPS` list, your `INSTALLED_APPS` should be something like this.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'your_app_name', #your app name here
]
```

Then you can add your views, models, and URLs to the newly created apps (Django will automatically these files for you, and you only have to edit them according to your needs)